# Settings API in WebOS

Tags: webos, mojo

I was wondering if there is a Mojo or Enyo equivalent to the Android Settings.System API where application can change settings like ring tone volume, time and date format, wifi on and off, et c?

Comment: It seems like it is the System Service that allows applications access system settings in WebOS. It's not very well documented, but there is an unconfirmed list of available settings at http://webos101.com/System_Service as well as an untested example.
If anyone could verify the information that would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be [officially documented](https://developer.palm.com/content/api/reference/services/system-services.html) anywhere, which means either that no one had time to document it or the API is still in flux.  Your best bet is to guess and check.  The `getPreferenceValues` call should be helpful once you know what keys you're interested in.